# Spring - changing property value based on container bean

Tags: spring

This is more of a design question. My project's structure is like this - I have a dozen frontend classes, some service layer classes and a single backend class which contacts an external system. I use spring to initialize and inject the backend class instance into the service class beans, and in turn the service class beans into the frontend class beans (as appropriate).

The frontend classes are (logically) divided into modules. The service layer and backend are common.

Now, my requirement is that the backend class methods need to send out a different value for a field to the external system, based on the module of the frontend class making the call.

To make it more simple, consider a (somewhat crude) usecase where the backend class connects to a DB for each method call. DB calls originated by module A's frontend classes, must always connect with the username "moduleA". Similarly all calls from module B must result in connections using username "moduleB". Note, the behavior itself is common regardless of caller -- just the username must be different.

Most trivial way is to let each frontend class bean have its own copy of service layer class bean, which in turn has its own copy of backend class bean. For eg, module A's frontend beans will refer to the moduleA service bean, which will refer to moduleA backend bean. I can inject module A's username into module A's backend bean in this case. Similarly there will be a set of bean definitions (frontend + service + backend) for moduleB.

But I don't want to create so many bean definitions. The other trivial way is to pass the value from frontend all the way to backend in all methods. But this is a widespread change. Is there a simpler way using Spring?

Answer (score 0):

You should try passing the values using thread local (if your modules are running inside the same JVM)
Be careful to clean the thread in a servlet filter via a finally method.